# Bash: Open multiple files in directory sequentially

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have 10 images that need to be opened using a specific program called abc (used as "abc "). But I want to open these in the program one by one and run through all of them by simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for example. So this would allow me to find the image I'm looking for relatively quickly.

I'm using:

```
for file in ./*; do echo $file; ~/Scripts/abc $file; done
```

It opens the first file, and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it doesn't return anything.

I'm completely new to bash and would really appreciate any tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in ./*; do echo $file; ~/Scripts/abc $file &; read; done
```